# Initiate facebook like script several times without parse-ing existing like buttons

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm using infinite scroll, and inside the elements I load at runtime I have a Facebook like button. Everything works the first time I call the script, however, it seems as if I can't load it more than once, and therefore the elements created when scrolling wont have a working Facebook button due to not existing when the script was loaded. Nothing happens if I do this after more content is loaded.

Looking at the script ( http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js ), it looks like the script will only run once per page, is there any way around this?

My code:

```
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];   
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.async=true;  
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

I am aware that a simple solution is  The JavaScript SDK that gives us a function called FB.XFBML.parse.

```
FB.XFBML.parse
```

Once the infinite scroll function is called, I could load more data by simply calling this function again to render the new plugins. But this parse's all the previously loaded like buttons on page. So if I have existing 20 like buttons, after the scroll and calling the Parse function, 10 more are like buttons are created but the previous once are parsed too.

So how do I work around this?

Comment: Perhaps `window.FB = null;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to documentation, you can do FB.XFBML.parse on specific element

```
  FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: It depends on your parse function, but generally you can implement something based on my solution, that use callback in FB.XFBML.parse() - http://jsfiddle.net/tC7an/